# How does the state of React work?

Tags: reactjs, state

My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/woyuditan26/bgwrfLxh/

```
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        tasks: prevState.tasks.concat(newTask),
        text: ''  ////  why the input text is not cleared when I clicked the button ?
      }));
```

Why the input text is not cleared when I clicked the button ?

Comment: Where do you use `text`?

Comment: Do we have a "debug-my-code" tag or similar?

Comment: I recommend you read this [react/docs/forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: because your form is 'uncontrolled' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is, you are using [uncontrolled element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) (because you didn't define the value property with input element), to make it as [controlled element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) you need to specify the value props with input element.

Like this:

```
<input type="text" value={this.props.text} onChange={this.handleTextChange}/>
```

Check the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqL156ka/).